# How to reduce specific Regex expression to 50 characters or less

Tags: regex

I am trying to match strings where there are two or more of the following words: Strength, Intelligence and Dexterity, with a value of 45 or higher. This an example of a string that would return a match:

```
+51 to Strength
+47 to Intelligence
+79 to maximum Life
+73 to maximum Mana
28% increased Rarity of Items found
+37% to Cold Resistance
```

The regex expression is to be entered in a game (Path of exile). The regex string can be **a maximum of 50 characters**.

**The fourth bird** has found a solution, but the string is more than 50 characters:

```
 \b[45][0-9] to (?:Str|Int|Dex)[\s\S]*?\b[45][0-9] to (?:Str|Int|Dex).
```

Is there a way to found a similar expression, but with 50 characters or less?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten it using a group and repeat that group with a quantifier, and write `[0-9]` as `\d` for example:

```
^(?:[\s\S]*?\b[45]\d to (?:Str|Int|Dex)){2}
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[\s\S]*?` Match any char as few as possible
  - `\b[45]\d to (?:Str|Int|Dex)` Match `4` or `5` followed by a digit,  `to`  and one of `Str` `Int` `Dex`
- `){2}` Close the non capture group and repeat it 2 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IXWrw7/1)